# UITextField click issue

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

I am new in ios development.

I have a UITextField. There I set a default text "Enter name".

When user tapped on the textfield, I want to clear the default text. If user tapped outside the textfield without entering any text, I want to show again the default text in it.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your default text as a `placeholder` property of your text field.